# Is there anyway to Prefill the form if we can't access the form html file?

Tags: javascript, html, url, autofill, password-encryption

I have a database with fields (site, username, password). I want a user to be able to share password to other user via a link (may be via e-mail). When the receiver clicks on the link, he must be redirected to the site with password and username filled into proper text-boxes.

example for site : https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login

> NOTE :  I don't have access to this form.

I want to mimic a feature which is provided by password sharing services like [lastpass](https://www.lastpass.com/). Which has this exact feature built. I want to know how can I fill those text boxes(username, password) once user has clicked on link.

Edit : I have tried web **scraping** with python Beautiful soup. But few sites like ICICI banks have stricter securities so I couldn't get these field names.

Comment: My advice dont do it. The username/password will be stored in webserver logs that may compromise. Instead, let user enter the credentials or use oAuth.

Comment: Share password to other users? Why? I don't think that it is possible without backend update.

Comment: See I think you are not getting the question. There is a boss user who has access to all sites, username, password. He wants to share username, password so that he can ask his assistants to do a job for him. But he doesn't want to share his id and pass permanently. If there is any other way I am all ears.

Comment: Is those sites owned by boss himself or other owned sites

Comment: Boss is also the user of my application, He is not owner. I am the owner of this password sharing application and I want to give this feature to boss user.

Answer (score 0):

url = `https://localhost/form/login.php?username=eliot&pass=123456`

**login.php**

```html
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_GET['username'];?>" name="username" placeholder="enter your username">
<input type="password" value="<?php echo $_GET['pass'];?>" name="password" placeholder="enter your password">
<button type="submit">Login<button>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> also do a note: sharing password through GET is not a secured way, ($_GET = url parameter)

Comment: -@Nisarg The above one is  what you expecting for but not at all secured still you need to move further atleast try out encryption

Comment: As I have written in question, I don't have access to the website. So this soln is no good for me anyhow thanks for your input.                                                       example for site : https://services.gst.gov.in/services/login                                       I want to apply prefill on this type of site.

Comment: @NisargGogate listen, that website using better secured way, i mean they only using post methord, so u cannot share password through url parameter, but you can make a custom form and make the form POST instead of GET, then point it to the submit directory of that site's. so when click submit button ur form, it will redirect to that websites url and login automatically